# Match nth number by regular expression(QRegularExpression)

Tags: regex, qt, c++11, qt5

I am trying to match the nth number in the string.

Ex : 0000_1111_2222_3333

The string[0] should be 0000, string[1] should be 1111 and so on

Following is my solution

```
QString find_nth_match(QRegularExpression const &reg, QString const &input, int nth)
{
    auto it = reg.globalMatch(input);
    QRegularExpressionMatch match;
    int count = 0;

    while(it.hasNext()){
        match = it.next();
        if(count == nth){
            return match.captured(1);
        }
        ++count;
    }

    return "no match";
}
```

I use it like following

```
qDebug()<<"nth match == "<<find_nth_match(QRegularExpression("(\\d+)"),
                                          "0000_1111_2222_3333",
                                          2);
```

it will print "nth match == 2222"

It is possible to match the nth number by regular expression?

Comment: Can `n` have a larger value than 9 ?

Comment: I think what you are doing is correct. If you need to get a capture group `n`, you can use `(?:\d+(?:_|$)){n-1}(\d+)`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wT0yQ1/2)

Comment: @ fjardon it can have a larger value than 9